# How to create a sed script to replace quotes in a file?

Tags: text-processing, sed, scripting

So I manually use the following two commands in succession on my data file, i.e. I trigger the second command after the first has finished updating the file:

```
sed -i 's/""""/" " /g' EXPERIMENT-20210729010003.FILE
sed -i 's/"""/" " /g' EXPERIMENT-20210729010003.FILE
```

How can i write this in a .sh script and pass file name as argument to the sh call?

EXPERIMENT-*.FILE comes everyday on my unix server. At any given point of time there can be only one Experiment file with a unique datetime value appended to its name.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could combine your two separate `sed` commands into one:

```bsh
sed -i -e 's/""""/" " /g' -e 's/"""/" " /g' file
```

or even,

```bsh
sed -i 's/"\{3,4\}/" " /g' file
```

(but only because `""""` is being replaced *before* `"""`; had you done the substitutions in the opposite order, then this last command would not be equivalent).

You could turn this into a shell script,

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

sed -i -e 's/""""/" " /g' -e 's/"""/" " /g' -- "$@"
```

... or into a shell function (in your `~.bashrc` file, for example),

```bsh
call_sed () {
    sed -i -e 's/""""/" " /g' -e 's/"""/" " /g' -- "$@"
}
```

The `--` in the command stops command line option processing and allows you to use the script or function on filenames starting with a dash.  The `"$@"` will expand to a list of filenames given to the script or function, each individually quoted.

You could use the script or function like so:

```
$ call_sed EXPERIMENT-*.FILE
```

With a single `sed` command like this, you could even make it an alias, but the quoting needs to be handled with care and I would recommend using a shell function instead:

```bsh
alias call_sed='sed -i -e "s/\"\"\"\"/\" \" /g" -e "s/\"\"\"/\" \" /g" --'
```

---

To make the `-i` option (which you may not want to use always) an option to the script:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

unset in_place

if [ "$1" = "-i" ]; then
    in_place=true
    shift
fi

sed ${in_place:+-i} -e 's/""""/" " /g' -e 's/"""/" " /g' -- "$@"
```

The `${in_place:+-i}` would expand to `-i` if `$in_place` is non-empty.  The variable would be non-empty if the first argument given to the script is `-i`.

The exact same modification could be made to the shell function variant of the code to make the shell function take an `-i` option.

Comment: A call to sed like `sed 's/"\{3,4\}/" " /g'` is a good enough regex to match both sequences of 4 double quotes `""""` and/or 3 double quotes `"""`.

Comment: @ImHere Since it will match the longest match first, it will produce the same result.  If `""""` had been replaced before `"""""`, the results would have been different.  I'll make a note in my answer. Thanks!

Comment: If you replace 3 `"""` first, there will be no 4 `""""` to replace anymore.

Comment: @ImHere Exactly, this is why your suggestion works in this case, but not if the user in the question had done the substitutions in the opposite order.

Comment: Thank you @Kusalananda. That was very detailed and useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you're looking for is:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
sed -i 's/""""/" " /g' $1
sed -i 's/"""/" " /g' $1
exit 0
```

Lets say you name the script `myscript.sh`. You'd use it like so:

```
./myscript.sh filename.txt
```

The `$1` is the first argument that is passed to the script, in this case `filename.txt`.

All a bash/shell script is, is just a bunch of commands that you *can* run manually, but instead automate those commands all in one.

Comment: Why would you want to force a zero exit status with `exit 0`?  It would hide the exit status of the (last) `sed` call.

Comment: True, just a force of habit honestly. lol

Comment: Thank you @CPH. this was useful. :)